# How to know history of all containers executed on Docker?

Tags: docker, containers

Is there any way to know all the containers that have or has been running or stoped on Docker and get the history of them ?

Comment: No, there isn't! As David Maze answered, that is not part of the Docker HTTP API. You can list all containers and images and perform `docker history` and `docker logs` on them. But once they are removed (`docker rm`), there is no way of obtaining it again. You can have a process that runs `docker events` and store it in a different place to obtain at least all the events that happened during some period.

Comment: Yeah, i know that but needed to perform this specific commands to have some info on some previous runing container, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That functionality is not part of the [Docker HTTP API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/) so it's not available to an application programmer.  There is only information about containers that currently exist; once you delete a container (either via `docker rm` or an equivalent API call) it is completely gone.